# How to inject text to the cursor focus

Tags: c#, interop, cursor

I am developing a .NET windows app that needs to insert text in the place where the cursor is. The cursor will be in a different application that I have no control over. I think the operating system needs to be used here to achieve this. Can you help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the text you want to insert into the clipboard

Find the window's handle:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
foreach (Process p in processes)
{
    IntPtr pFoundWindow = p.MainWindowHandle;
    // Do something with the handle...
}
```

Send a "Ctrl+V" message to the window using pinvoke, see http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendMessage

Comment: pinvoke.net is down at the moment :( This sounds pretty cool, I'd like to try it myself.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy is to use the [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) class on Windows.Forms.

Otherwise use the [SendMessage](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendMessage) from the windows api to send key by key ([some information](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-49901.html) on this).

Do not use the clipboard, the user typically does not want that, and does not expect that.